# How do you enable inline details in Visual Studio 2017? They disappeared after update

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-extensions

Using Visual Studio 2017, C#, and .Net.  Repository is stored on Github.

Before Win10 update, there were messages over each function and class.  It would tell when the function was last edited, how many times it was committed, the number of times it was referenced, etc.

I'm not sure how I enabled this feature.  All my settings reset to default after the update.

What is this feature and how do I enable it?

Comment: Search settings for "Code lens".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable the CodeLens under VS IDE Tools->Options->Text Editor:

[image]